# Create airflow pools programatically

Tags: docker, airflow

I have `airflow` running on a docker container. I'm working with airflow `version 2.0.2`.

I know that I can actually create pools via the UI. But I'm looking for a way to create the pools programmatically on docker build via a `pools.json` file. Any way to help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this programmatically via the [REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/post_pool) or [CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#pools). The REST API allows for adding pools over HTTP one by one. The CLI has a [command](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#import_repeat1) for importing pools from a JSON file:

```sh
airflow pools import [-h] [-v] FILEPATH
```

For example:

```json
{
    "pool_1": {"slots": 5, "description": ""},
    "pool_2": {"slots": 5, "description": "test"}
}
```

The format is: `"[pool name]": {"slots": [nr of slots], "description": "[description]"}`

```sh
airflow pools import pools.json
```

The command works idempotent, so you can run it as many times as you like. Changes to existing pools result in an update, new pools will be created. Removing a pool from `pools.json` doesn't remove the pool in Airflow -- you'll have to do that manually.

Since it works idempotent, you can build a `pools.json` file into your Airflow image and run `airflow pools import` at the start of your container process, so that pools are checked at the start of every Airflow container.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly fine !

Answer (score 3):

Alternative way to create & use a pool in your DAG using python code (Rather than ui / cli)

```py
# pools.py
from airflow.models import Pool

# USAGE: DONT FORGET .pool: @task(pool=s3_pool.**pool**)
s3_pool= Pool.create_or_update_pool(
    "s3_pool",
    slots=1,
    description="Limit to 1 run of S3 ",
)
```

and your dag file:

```py
# my_dag.py

# A generic operator
MyOperator(..., pool=s3_pool.pool)

# or using taskflow API
@task(pool=s3_pool.pool)
def my_task_name():
   ...
```